# how to get device token for ANS(Amazon Notification Service) ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Could you please any one help me for generation device register token for ANS(Amazon notification service) in Ionic framework.

Answer (score 1):

uuid  = (ionic.Platform.device() && ionic.Platform.device().uuid || false);
Must be used after device ready